# shared preferences keep disappearing

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using the shared preferences to store login credentials for my app. Everything works fine except with one user. After a certain amount of time the shared preferences seem to be reset or cleared somehow. I've adjusted my app for this user to never clear his shared preferences anymore. This way I can be sure that it is not my app's fault. But even after this modification his credentials get cleared, so I'm suspecting something else is going on with his device.

Do any of you have suggestions on how to approach this problem? I've been thinking about creating another app which sets a fileobserver to monitor the preference file. This way I hope to see when the file gets cleared/deleted. Maybe there are apps who can do this already? I'm even willing to make the preference file available to other apps for checking. Is there any one way to diagnose this problem? I'm sure it's not my app doing the clearing / resetting...

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have only *one* user with this problem? How many users do you have? At least 100? If so it's probably a bad device. Don't waste time chasing this.

Comment: Well, the one user is my boss :-) and this app will probably be rolled out to thousands of users. At the moment I'm testing and this is one problem I've not been able to resolve and I'd like to know where it is coming from. So far I've tested on about 6 devices.

Comment: Oh, that's quite unfortunate. Install any app from the market on his device and save preferences. If they work, the problem is your app. I assume you're calling editor.commit()?

Comment: He says other apps work fine :-( I'm using this code: 

getSharedPreferences( "SPrefs", 0 )
.edit()
.putString("PREF_USR", mUsername.getText().toString())
.putString("PREF_PWD", mPassword.getText().toString())
.putBoolean("PREF_SAVED", true)
.commit();

After this I never call clear on the preferences anymore, yet they disappear...

Comment: That's a pretty long chain you've got there. Why not do SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit() and then save each one individually. I am going to guess you are getting an NPE on one of those, like mUsername.getText() could throw an NPE if mUsername was null.

Comment: I guess you are right. I will 'de-chain' my commit and check for errors on every step. Hopefully this will resolve the problem. However, when I tested it, the credentials were stored and retrieved just fine. It's only after a while that they are cleared somehow.

Comment: When you write complicated code like that you are just asking for bugs. Each phone is a tiny bit different.

Answer (score 2):

Several things to consider. First, if you can, simply use a database as they are much more dependable. Second, do not use a SharedPreferences object across processes, which is likely not applicable to this situation. Third, when reading SharedPreferences you have to use the same precautions when writing them. Use a single SharedPreference object, and a single Editor object. Pass the SharedPreferences object around to your methods and class, you don't have to reuse the Editor. In the past I've had a user a day complain about SharedPreferences getting deleted, but once I implemented some of these logical steps my users stopped annoying me. Bare in mind, just like you said, it's rare. 1 in 1500 users is is a negligible percentage, but even a single user can leave a bad comment :-)