# SharedPreferences are dissapearing after a few minutes.

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a strange problem and I havent been able to find a solution to it. 
My SharedPreferences are dissapearing after a few minutes I create a shared preference editor and then commit every change I make. I then get the SharedPreferences values to use using:

```
settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);

if(settings.contains("accesstoken")){

    // create a string that stores the accesstoken from our settings.
    String str_access = settings.getString("accesstoken", null);

    if(accesstoken_file_data != null){
        str_access = accesstoken_file_data;
    }
```

After a while the access token I stored along with all other data stored in SharedPreferences doesn't appear to exist... Thats if I leave my phone for a few minutes. I am developing with a HTC One X.

I am using this method to add values:

```
                            String accesstoken = "someVal";

                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                            editor.putString("accesstoken", accesstoken);
                            editor.commit();
```

I have not found any viable solutions to this yet... if someone could help or direct me that would be great thanks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512917/shared-preferences-keep-disappearing

Comment: Akki please explain how this helps answer my question.

Comment: ok i made all my calls local ill post an update if it fixes it or not. Thanks guys :).

Comment: @AndersMetnik actually my suggestion was because its not clear where the code makes global existence or not. not becase it will screws up stuff.

Comment: Thankyou for your more specified answer answer Akki. I appreciate it :).

Comment: Its only me who reads the code you see. There is no other developers on this project so code layout is not a problem. But if it mechanically causes a problem then it should be changed, hence I have made every call local and am testing it out as we speak :).

Comment: @jimbob you should always try to keep conventions, and your code as readable as possible, even though it will only be you reading it. For nothing else, then for occations like this, when you need help.
It will also be easier for yourself to bugtrace when you start doing larger projects.

Comment: true that. I changed it all by the way... But unfortunately it has not resolved the problem.

Comment: Hopefully you've solved your problem by now, but if not...
Where do you initialize accesstoken_file_data?

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences have an unfortunate tendency to wipe its data if the app crashes or is force stopped-

And all saving methods (with the exception of external storage) are wiped if the app data is cleared from settings

You could try to use a different saving method for storing the data. You have databases (SQLite), internal and external storage. The last two are file-based.